# Annotation error in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations

I have this piece of code in my Java entity class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="Student.getAll", query="SELECT e FROM Student e"));
public class Student implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int studentId;
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column   
    private String lastname;
    @Column
    private int yearLevel;

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
```

And more methods from then on. The error im getting is after the `@Entity` annotation. It says "class, interface, or enum expected". It's weird because im watching a tutorial and there's no error there. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't importing `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` and `javax.persistence.NamedQueries`, and you have an extraneous semicolon at the end of your annotations.

Also, if you only have the one query, you can put `@NamedQuery` directly on the entity class instead of wrapping it.

Comment: I did it, but the error still persists. I edited the question including the imports.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini Just noticed the other error and updated my answer.

Comment: Even removing the `@NamedQueries` there's still the error. But I think the semicolon thing did the trick.